# Ubuntu 14.04.1 persistent on USB flash drive deleted Windows 7

Tags: boot, windows, live-usb, data-recovery, persistence

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 persistent on a usb flash drive using Linux Live usb creator http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ and everything went fine. I gave it persistent memory for the flash drive to store changes. Once I booted up from the drive, it took a long time to boot up and after it booted, I clicked live mode so it wouldn't affect my computer. After that, I couldn't access windows files or anything so I then restarted it and went to BIOS settings and let it boot from windows. When it boots, it does NOTHING! Nothing works and not even the HP recovery manager that came with my computer doesn't boot up! I then decided to boot from the usb again to Ubuntu and I went to the hard drive and it says only "1 gig" of space used! I had a bunch of videos and files on windows that I NEED! PLEASE HELP! If there is no way to get windows back or my files, is there at least a way recover my files such as photos, music, and videos because it appears there is nothing on the HHD! Here goes a picture of my  Here is a picture of Gparted https://imageshack.com/i/ey4aBBO3j

Comment: Ok, whatever we see in this image, is definitely NOT a hard drive formatted by Windows. It seems you have accidentaly replaced Windows by Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there anyway to recover the lost data on the HHD such as my photos, videos, and music?

Comment: If you're lucky, you may recover some of the data: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery